# Uninstall Kyngchaos' frameworks

Tags: macos, gdal, qgis

I'm trying to uninstall the Kyngchaos' **gdal** framework but still haven't been able to find a way to do it.

It seems there is no info at Kyngchaos website so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I found out that the *ReadMe.rtf* of the installation *.dmg* has the instructions of how to uninstall each framework.

In case of GDAL 2.2 the instructions are:

> Drag GDAL.framework, GEOS.framework, PROJ.framework, SQLite3.framework and UnixImageIO.framework from /Library/Frameworks to the Trash.  Also trash /Library/Application Support/GDAL and ~/Library/Application Support/GDAL (if it exists).
>
> Run these commands in a Terminal:

`sudo pkgutil --forget org.gdal.gdal22-framework-yosemite`

`sudo pkgutil --forget net.refractions.geos-framework-yosemite`

`sudo pkgutil --forget org.maptools.proj-framework-yosemite`

`sudo pkgutil --forget org.sqlite.sqlite3-framework-yosemite`

`sudo pkgutil --forget com.kyngchaos.UnixImageIO-framework-F-yosemite`

> Python
>
> Use pip to uninstall the python components:

`sudo pip3 uninstall gdal`

`sudo pip3 uninstall proj`

`sudo pip3 uninstall shapely`

Comment: can use `sudo pkgutil --pkgs | grep gdal` (etc.) to find the specific packages to remove on your machine—on my machine there was `com.kyngchaos.matplotlib-mtlion` as well

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Guillermo's answer. The frameworks are hidden, to access them on `MacOS`, enter `Cmd + Shift + G` from finder then `/Library/Frameworks` enter